# Choosing error function for regression

Tags: regression, unbalanced-classes, loss-functions, zero-inflation

I have a dataset with ~100K samples and non-negative continuous target variable. 99% of target values are zeros and the remaining 1% are right-skewed. Here are the deciles (0 and 1 correspond to min and max):

```
0.0       1.990
0.1      14.971
0.2      19.990
0.3      27.294
0.4      37.980
0.5      47.990
0.6      62.174
0.7      84.512
0.8     123.094
0.9     270.337
1.0    2933.610
```

So here's my problem. I need to choose an error function but whichever I take has certain drawbacks for my data. The dataset represents mobile apps' revenue and I believe that there are some common approaches to such data. Any ideas and recommendations will be highly helpful.

Here are my concerns:

- MSE: I suppose that it will punish right-most values;
- MAE: an error of 100 when predicting 2000 and when predicting 20 are intuitively two different errors and the second one should be punished more;
- MAPE: I'd like to use MAPE but there are two serious issues:

  - it doesn't work with zero targets and I definitely need zeroes;
  - it can punish overestimation much more than underestimation and I believe that both types of errors should be treated the same;
- MSLE (mean squared logarithmic loss): it seems to solve above-mentioned problems with MAPE but I feel it highly unintuitive: an error of 3 means that my prediction might be 3 times smaller or 3 times larger than the true value: how should I use it?

Whichever loss function I consider, I face either 99% of zeros or long right skew. Possibly I miss some function that nicely fits this situation? Or, may be< I should somehow separate the two cases and punish model for non-predicting zero in one way and for errors in predicting non-zero in some other? What are the best practices for such data?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Perhaps a two stage model would be helpful. Predict who will make a purchase, then predict spending conditional on making at least 1 purchase.

Comment: How well is your non-zero data fit by a log normal distribution? My question comes from the age-old wisdom "first, take the log of money." It has never let me down, but there is always a first. Also, you may wish to look up zero-augmented distributions: a delta function at zero PLUS a relevant distribution above zero. Maybe this: https://rdrr.io/github/rmcelreath/rethinking/man/dzagamma2.html ?

Comment: Have you considered some measure related to relative error? This would measure by what % of the actual measure your error in off, rather than the actual magnitude or that error

Comment: @jsk, I indeed plan to use this two-step approach but not sure how I should evaluate the results.

Comment: @PeterLeopold The fit is not bad. I'll check your link, thank you.

Comment: @David I consider using the two-stage process and using MAPE for positive predictions. But with this approach I don't know how to compute overall error that includes errors on zeroes.

Comment: @Igor Maybe divide by the prediccion rather than the actual value, or by the average of both

Comment: @Igor. The two stage approach is identical conceptually  to the approach suggested by Peter. You can check the fit of each model separately. Predicting who will purchase is a classification problem with a bunch of standard metrics.  In the end you can combine the predictions into a single prediction,  $0*p(Y_i=0) + \hat{Y}_i*p(Y_i>0)$, which makes it clear that there are two sources of error you care about. Can I predict who will spend, and if they spend, how well can I predict how much they spend. Other metrics depend upon what you really want to predict.  Total revenue? Likely spenders?

Comment: @David. That sounds interesting. I'll try it.

Comment: @jsk I'd like to predict revenue for individual transactions rather than total revenue. And I plan to use the two stage approach but indeed don't understand how to combine errors. Since I want to use the probabilistic output of the first stage, I plan to use cross-entropy here. And I really feel MAPE as an intuitive metric for revenue target. But how can I evaluate the overall performance?

Comment: @Igor once you have a model that you are confident  accurately predicts individual transactions, what will you do next? Are there any decisions you are trying to make based on the predictions? Knowing how the predictions will ultimately be used may affect how to evaluate the performance.